# Derivation of $f(x)=\prod_{m=0}^{n}(x-x_m)^{m+1}\tan(x), x_m=m\pi, M>0$

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\prod_{m=0}^{n}(x-x_m)^{m+1}\tan(x), x_m=m\pi,   M>0$$

I would like to calulate the numeric root of: $n\pi, n\ge0.$

In order to do that, I want to use Newton-Rapshon technique. And for that I would like to know what's the derivation of the function above, My guess would be that i need to do derivate: $(x-x_m)^{m+1}\tan(x)$.

But i saw that the correct answer is:

$$ f'(x)= 1/\cos^2x\cdot\prod_{m=0}^{n}(x-m\pi)^{m+1}+\tan x\cdot\sum_{m=0}^M (m+1)(x-m \pi  )^m\cdot \prod_{n=0,n \ne m}^M(x-n\pi)^{n+1}$$

My question is - Why?

Comment: Would it be simpler to take logarithms of both sides and compute the derivative $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ as a sum ? From a computing point of view, I think it could be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use product rule:

$$(f_1 f_2 ...f_n)'=f_1' f_2 ... f_n +f_1 f_2' f_3...f_n +f_1 f_2 f_3' f_4...f_n +...+f_1 f_2 ...f_{n-1} f_n'$$

Also in your function, derivative of $\tan{x}$ is $\sec^2{x}$, which is the same as $\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}$.